# Footcite that changes format on second citation

Tags: biblatex, footnotes

I'm writing a report for the university. They're being very specific about specifying formatting for citation. Although I suspect the mentor won't be very strict, I'm still interested in having as close output from LaTeX as possible. I'm an utter newbie with LaTeX, so I'm learning as I go.

Having picked up a template from another Croatian university that has a very similar format, I've began writing my text and customizing the template as I go. The issue I ran into is with citations.

Here are the (translated) instructions on citing:

> Citing: On every page, place reference into a footnote. See appendix for information on format.
>   Literature: At the end; list authors alphabetically.

And:

> Note: For second and other citations of the same bibliographical unit, you should list the following: First and last name of the author, in parenthesis a numerical identifier of the footnote where it's first listed, number of page where it's first listed.

So far, I switched from `bibtex` to `biblatex` and `biber` in order to make use of `\footcite`. I've played with some defaults (`style=numeric`, …), but I feel that as a newbie it'd take me a long, long time to figure out how to get this exact behavior.

**How would I go about** forcing full bibliography entry to appear in the first reference to an entry in a `\footcite`, then having subsequent entries display author name, first footnote's ID and first footnote's page number, while at the same time having full entry appear in the Literature section?

Comment: Try `\usepackage[style=verbose-note,pageref]{biblatex}`.

Comment: …wow, that was fast! Thanks. It doesn't seem to include author's first name, but it's already awesome and seems to match the requirements. I'd accept it were it an answer!

Comment: I'm working on including the first name as we speak. ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\usepackage[style=verbose-note,pageref]{biblatex}` does most of what you want. Here's how to add first names to follow-up citations (and replace the comma with parentheses):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=verbose-note,pageref]{biblatex}

\DeclareNameAlias{labelname}{first-last}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchbibmacro{footcite:note}{%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \printtext%
}{%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \printtext[parens]%
}{}{}
\xapptobibmacro{footcite:note}{\nopunct}{}{}% optional

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

Some text \autocite{A01}.

\clearpage

\null\vfill% just for the example

Some more text \autocite{A01}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How can I remove the "see n. 1"? I'm doing a Turabian report  and it's supposed to be [Author's last name] + [space] + [page#].